# how to solve data requests in react js post method?

Tags: node.js, reactjs

trying to post data request through axios

[image: Post method imgae]

[image: Get Method Image]

i want to fetch post body down side when Player,channelName, are same as the Get method Api so i am not able to Match that request by dynamically Please help!. When I am using mapping(get method ) to assign value and reffer to them in post data but it's calling him undefined and not pointing them. I want same get method api forword toward on at time{channel name,port, ip address,} the post function so that same api body(below in postman ) access to me https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-jang-3gdgh?file=/src/App.js full code here

```
function getPostData() {    
    axios({      
      method: 'post',
      url: 'http://localhost:9763/api/getPlayerStatus',
      data: {
        IpAddress: ip,
        Port: port,
        ChannelName: Channelname,
        PlayerName: player
      },
      headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
      auth: {
        username: 'admin',
        password: 'password'
      }
    }).then(response => {
      console.log(response.data);
      Postdata([response.data]);
    }).catch(error => {
      console.log(error);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Line 32 should read `params`, not `parms`. I think that may be causing the issue.

Also please wrap your functions getfetchData and getPostData in a `useCallback` hook, otherwise your component will rerender unnecessarily.